# How to use IFNULL with yii CDbCriteria?

Tags: yii, ifnull

In yii, i have a `CDbCriteria` with select property as:

```
$criteria->select = "IFNULL(t.cccid,'Default')";
```

That is I want to return 'Default' if t.cccid is NULL. Else value of t.cccid should be returned/

The problem is that `IFNULL` is not being recognized. I get error as:

*trying to select an invalid column "'Default')"*

I have also tried:

```
$criteria->select = "IFNULL(t.cccid,'Default') as cccid";
```

and then i get syntax error.

Can anyone help me on how to use `IFNULL` in `$criteria->select`?

Answer (score 3):

Use of [CDbExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression) would help you here

```
$criteria->select = new CDbExpression("IFNULL(t.cccid,'Default') cccid");
```

or (to select * , or other columns, use array )

```
$criteria->select = array(
        '*', 
        new CDbExpression("IFNULL(t.cccid,'Default') cccid"),
);
```